# Css why isn't my <a> tag in the middle of my "div". valign=middle does not work

Tags: html, angularjs, css, django-templates

This is the code for my div:

```
 <div height="45" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 6px; 
color: #ffffff;line-height:15px;background-color: #24b646;width: 180px;padding: 0px;margin: 30px 0 30px 60px;height: 45px;"
class="mobileWidth100 mobilePadding0">
     <a valign="middle" width="auto" href="" target="_blank" alias="" style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
     text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:1px;margin: auto;height: 45px;
     line-height: 15px;">{% trans 'Manage Team'%}</a>
 </div>
```

I set a height of 45px on my div. and the a I've set valign to the middle, and even set the margin to auto, but still no luck. It looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following css on the element inside the div (ie the a tag)

display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;

```css
a{
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:1px;height: 45px;line-height: 15px;vertical-align: middle;display:table-cell;
}

div{

font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 14px;
border-radius: 6px; 
color: #ffffff;
line-height:15px;
background-color: #24b646;
width: 180px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 30px 0 30px 60px;
height: 45px;    

}
```

```html
<div height="45" align="center" valign="middle" style=""
class="mobileWidth100 mobilePadding0">
     <a width="auto" href="" target="_blank" alias="" style="">Example</a>
 </div>

<div height="45" align="center" valign="middle" style=""
class="mobileWidth100 mobilePadding0">
     <a width="auto" href="" target="_blank" alias="" style="">Example over<br>two lines !!!</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: changing to table-cell and vertical align didn't work for some reason, had to remove the margin: 0px; or margin: auto; from the anchor and after it worked. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you the best way to handle such cases.
To make vertical align middle, there are 2 display properties possible.
 1. display:table-cell, 2. display:inline-block
 but in both the case the element that needs to be aligned vertically also needs a reference to measure the height so it could get the vertical middle point.

### html

```
<div>
<span></span>
<a>APPEAR IN MIDDLE</a>
</div>
```

### css

```
div span, div a{display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}
div span, div{height: 200px}
div span{margin-left:-1px; width:1px;}
```

**EXPECT THIS WILL HELP YOU**

Answer (score 0):

Add `transform: translateY(-50%);-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* Safari & Chrome */
-moz-transform:translateY(-50%)
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);` IN your **anchor tag style**.